# Split Set into multiple columns Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
        IDs            Types
0      1001            {251}
1      1013       {251, 101}
2      1004       {251, 701}
3      3011           {251}
4      1014            {701}
5      1114            {251}
6      1015            {251}
```

where `df['Types']` has sets in each row. I want to convert this column into multiple columns such that I can get the following output

```
        IDs    Type1   Type2  
0      1001     251      -
1      1013     251     101
2      1004     251     701
3      3011     251      -
4      1014     701      -     
5      1114     251      -
6      1015     251      -
```

Currently, I am using the following code to achieve this

```
pd.concat([df['Types'].apply(pd.Series), df['IDs']], axis = 1)
```

But it return the following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 48, in <module>
    df = pd.concat([df['Types'].apply(pd.Series), df['IDs']], axis = 1)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2294, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1207, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:66124)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 223, in __init__
    "".format(data.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'set' type is unordered
```

Please guide me how can I get the desired output. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `DataFrame` constructor first, then rename columns and last [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

But if use `fillna` with some string, it can be problem, because get mixed numeric with strings(`-`) data and some pandas functions can be broken.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['Types'].values.tolist()) \
        .rename(columns = lambda x: 'Type{}'.format(x+1)) \
        .fillna('-')
print (df1)
   Type1 Type2
0    251     -
1    251   101
2    251   701

df2 = pd.concat([df['IDs'], df1], axis = 1)
print (df2)
    IDs  Type1 Type2
0  1001    251     -
1  1013    251   101
2  1004    251   701
```

Another slowier solution:

```
df1 = df['Types'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))) \
                 .rename(columns =lambda x: 'Type{}'.format(x+1)) \
                 .fillna('-')

df2 = pd.concat([df['IDs'], df1], axis = 1)
print (df2)
    IDs  Type1 Type2
0  1001  251.0     -
1  1013  251.0   101
2  1004  251.0   701
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking why I need to convert the set into list ?

Comment: I am not sure, but this solution is faster as `.apply(Series)`, but `.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))` can works.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(df.Types.values.tolist()).add_prefix('Types_').fillna('-').rename(columns={'Types_0':'Type1','Types_1':'Type2'})

df = pd.concat([df.drop('Types',axis=1), temp], axis=1)

    IDs  Types_0  Types_1
0  1001      251      NaN
1  1013      251    101.0
2  1001      251    701.0
```

Edit: I missed the `('-')` for missing values, should be good now.

Edit2: Column names as @jezrael pointed out

Comment: I think your output is a bit different as OP want, please check it.

Comment: I think `Types_0  Types_1`

Comment: You are correct. I would simply use a `rename` convention, I'll change mine but your answer already provides this :thumbs up:

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
df['Type1'] = df['Types'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[0])
df['Type2'] = df['Types'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[1] if len(x) > 1 else '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner (very similar to [@DmitryPolonskiy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43453727/5741205)):

```
In [96]: df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Types').values.tolist(), index=df.index)
                   .add_prefix('Type_')) \
           .fillna('-')
Out[96]:
    IDs  Type_0 Type_1
0  1001     251      -
1  1013     251    101
2  1004     251    701
```